# Speeding up my BOM calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a fairly small MRP application that consists of a sales order book, a bill of materials and a materials resource planning report.

The sales order book is simply a list of items, quantities and due dates.
The bill of materials is a flat list of each item, the sub components of that item and quantities like so: [ParentItemID] [ComponentItemID] [Qty]

I then also add in my Purchase Orders so the users can see a running balance.

It (should) be fairly trivial to compute.

The MRP report works fine functionally, however it takes about 90 seconds to run which is obviously frustrating for my users. I am currently using a queue to store the data and my entire code looks like this:

```
    public void MRPCalcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
//Calculate MRP Report
{
    //kick off a timer
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    //Flip the panels to hide the button
    panel1.Visible = false;
    panel2.Visible = true;
    Page.Title = "MRP Report"; //set the title so we can tell if it's finished from the task bar

    //Create DataTable to hold items
    var dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("ItemID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("QtyIn", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
    dt.Columns.Add("QtyOut", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
    dt.Columns.Add("DueDate", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));

    var db = new CS3Entities(); // should these be calls to DAL?

    //ADD SALES ORDERS
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //read orderbook in
    var orderBook = (from ob in db.SalesOrderItems
                     where ob.QtyOutstanding > 0
                     //where ob.ItemID == "9783B" //whilst testing, remove in production
                     select new { ob.ItemID, ob.QtyOutstanding, ob.DueDate });

    //create a queue to store temporary work, the line items are Orders
    var q1 = new Queue<OrderItem>();

    foreach (var item in orderBook) //loop through the order book
    {
        //Copy order book to queue to start off with
        var orderBookArray = new OrderItem
                                 {
                                     ItemID = item.ItemID,
                                     QtyIn = 0,
                                     QtyOut = item.QtyOutstanding,
                                     DueDate = item.DueDate
                                 };

        q1.Enqueue(orderBookArray); //adds line item to queue
    }

    //start calculating the BoM items
    try
    {
        do //main working loop
        {
            var testItem = q1.Peek(); //pull out next line item in queue

            var testItemID = testItem.ItemID; //pull out ItemID from line item
            var testQty = testItem.QtyOut; //pull out Qty from line item
            var testDueDate = testItem.DueDate; //pull out ItemID from line item

            //determines Bill OF Materials for each item
            var bills = (
                    from b in db.BillOfMaterials
                    where b.ItemID == testItemID
                    select new { b.ComponentItemID, b.Qty }
                    );

            if (bills.Any()) //if line item has any sub components
            {
                //add each sub comopnent to the queue
                foreach (var bill in bills)
                {
                    var bomArray = new OrderItem
                                       {
                                           ItemID = bill.ComponentItemID,
                                           QtyOut = bill.Qty*testQty,
                                           QtyIn = 0,
                                           DueDate = testDueDate
                                       };

                    q1.Enqueue(bomArray);
                }

                q1.Dequeue(); //Remove item from queue after all sub components have been added
            }
            else //if no items in Bill Of Materials, must be "leaf" component, add it to "final" table
            {
                AddToItems(dt, testItemID, 0, testQty, testDueDate); //add item to data table as QtyOut
                q1.Dequeue(); //Remove item from queue
            }

        } while (q1.Count != 0); //end of do loop, until queue is empty
    }
    catch
    {
        ErrorLbl.Text = "ERROR"; //if something goes wrong
    }

    //Queue should now be empty and DataTable dt holds all final items for purchase

    //ADD PURCHASE ORDERS
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //read purchase orders in
    var purchaseOrderItems = (from poi in db.PurchaseOrderItems
                              join po in db.PurchaseOrders on poi.PurchaseOrderID equals po.PurchaseOrderID
                              where po.PurchaseOrderCancelled != true && 
                                    po.PurchaseOrderDeleted != true && 
                                    poi.Balance > 0 && 
                                    poi.LineItemComplete != true

                              orderby poi.DueDate ascending 

                              select new { poi.ItemID, poi.Balance, poi.DueDate }).ToList(); //Is a list faster than the database calls?

    foreach (var item in purchaseOrderItems) //loop through the purchase orders and append them to the temp table
    {
        //add purchase order items to data table as QtyIn
        AddToItems(dt, item.ItemID, Convert.ToDecimal(item.Balance), 0, Convert.ToDateTime(item.DueDate));
    }

    //SORT RESULTS
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Sort and group the raw data
    var sorteditems = //sort and group the data table to show sum of qty per day per item
        (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
        orderby p.Field<string>("ItemID") , p.Field<DateTime>("DueDate")
        group p by new {ItemID = p.Field<string>("ItemID"), DueDate = p.Field<DateTime>("DueDate")}
        into g

        select new
                   {
                       g.Key.ItemID,
                       g.Key.DueDate,
                       QtyIn = g.Sum(p => p.Field<decimal>("QtyIn")),
                       QtyOut = g.Sum(p => p.Field<decimal>("QtyOut"))
                   }).ToList();

    //Create second DataTable to hold sorted and grouped report items
    //tried to use same datatable dt but it didn't work, no hardship to instantiate another
    var dt2 = new DataTable();

    dt2.Columns.Add("ItemID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt2.Columns.Add("QtyIn", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
    dt2.Columns.Add("QtyOut", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
    dt2.Columns.Add("DueDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));

    foreach (var item in sorteditems) //loop through the sorted results
    {
        //Move the sorted and grouped items into the datatable
        AddToItems(dt2, item.ItemID, Convert.ToDecimal(item.QtyIn), Convert.ToDecimal(item.QtyOut), Convert.ToDateTime(item.DueDate));
    }

    Session["MRPTable"] = dt2; //save datatable to session for recall later by repeater

    //Set repeater datasource to unique item list with details
    var itemslist = from si in sorteditems
                    group si by new { si.ItemID } into sig //equivilent to DISTINCT

                    join i in db.Items
                    on sig.Key.ItemID equals i.ItemID

                    select new
                    {
                        i.ItemID,
                        i.ItemName,
                        i.StocktakeCost,
                        i.ItemROP,
                        i.ItemROQ,
                        i.ItemUOM,
                        i.ItemStock
                    };

    Repeater1.DataSource = itemslist; //note repeater contains a GridView that contains the line items
    Repeater1.DataBind(); //Fire the repeater

    //time finished
    DateTime finishTime = DateTime.Now;

    //Set the start time label
    TimeStart.Text = startTime.TimeOfDay.ToString();

    //Set finish time
    TimeFinish.Text = finishTime.TimeOfDay.ToString();

    TimeTaken.Text = (finishTime - startTime).Minutes.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " Minute(s), " + (finishTime - startTime).Seconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " Seconds";

    //Add to activity log
    ActivityDAL.AddNewLog("MRP Report", "Generated", TimeTaken.Text, "N/A", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

}
```

Can anyone see where I can improve the speed of the report and where I have made any obvious errors.

As I said, the report works fine but is slow.

Any help appreciated

Comment: you should first determine which part of your code takes the most time and start there. In cases like this i usually add some debug logging between the steps to narrow down the parts of the process i should improve.

Answer (score 1):

```
var bills = (from b in db.BillOfMaterials
             where b.ItemID == testItemID
             select new { b.ComponentItemID, b.Qty });
```

above code should be outside the do {} while() loop, otherwise db.BillOfMaterials will be looped through as many times as the while loop runs

```
public void MRPCalcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
//Calculate MRP Report
{
    //kick off a timer
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    //Flip the panels to hide the button
    panel1.Visible = false;
    panel2.Visible = true;
    Page.Title = "MRP Report"; //set the title so we can tell if it's finished from the task bar

    //Create DataTable to hold items
    var dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("ItemID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("QtyIn", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
    dt.Columns.Add("QtyOut", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
    dt.Columns.Add("DueDate", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));

    var db = new CS3Entities(); // should these be calls to DAL?

    //ADD SALES ORDERS
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //read orderbook in
    var orderBook = (from ob in db.SalesOrderItems
                     where ob.QtyOutstanding > 0
                     //where ob.ItemID == "9783B" //whilst testing, remove in production
                     select new OrderItem
                                 {
                                     ItemID = ob.ItemID,
                                     QtyIn = 0,
                                     QtyOut = ob.QtyOutstanding,
                                     DueDate = ob.DueDate
                                 };);

    //create a queue to store temporary work, the line items are Orders
    var q1 = new Queue<OrderItem>();

    foreach (var item in orderBook) //loop through the order 
        q1.Enqueue(orderBookArray); //adds line item to queue

    //determines Bill OF Materials for each item
    var billDict = db.BillOfMaterials.
                   GroupBy(b => b.ItemID).
                   ToDictionary(
                       g => g.Key, 
                       g => g.Select(b => new { b.ComponentItemID, b.Qty }).ToList()
                   );

    //start calculating the BoM items
    try
    {
        do //main working loop
        {
            var testItem = q1.Peek(); //pull out next line item in queue

            var testItemID = testItem.ItemID; //pull out ItemID from line item
            var testQty = testItem.QtyOut; //pull out Qty from line item
            var testDueDate = testItem.DueDate; //pull out ItemID from line item

            if (billDict.ContainsKey(testItemID)) //if line item has any sub components
            {
                var bills = billDict[testItemID];
                //add each sub comopnent to the queue
                foreach (var bill in bills)
                {
                    var bomArray = new OrderItem
                                       {
                                           ItemID = bill.ComponentItemID,
                                           QtyOut = bill.Qty*testQty,
                                           QtyIn = 0,
                                           DueDate = testDueDate
                                       };

                    q1.Enqueue(bomArray);
                }
            }
            else //if no items in Bill Of Materials, must be "leaf" component, add it to "final" table
            {
                AddToItems(dt, testItemID, 0, testQty, testDueDate); //add item to data table as QtyOut
            }

            q1.Dequeue(); //Remove item from queue

        } while (q1.Count != 0); //end of do loop, until queue is empty
    }
    catch
    {
        ErrorLbl.Text = "ERROR"; //if something goes wrong
    }

    //Queue should now be empty and DataTable dt holds all final items for purchase

    //ADD PURCHASE ORDERS
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //read purchase orders in
    var purchaseOrderItems = (from poi in db.PurchaseOrderItems
                              join po in db.PurchaseOrders on poi.PurchaseOrderID equals po.PurchaseOrderID
                              where po.PurchaseOrderCancelled != true && 
                                    po.PurchaseOrderDeleted != true && 
                                    poi.Balance > 0 && 
                                    poi.LineItemComplete != true

                              orderby poi.DueDate ascending 

                              select new { poi.ItemID, poi.Balance, poi.DueDate }).ToList(); //Is a list faster than the database calls?

    foreach (var item in purchaseOrderItems) //loop through the purchase orders and append them to the temp table
    {
        //add purchase order items to data table as QtyIn
        AddToItems(dt, item.ItemID, Convert.ToDecimal(item.Balance), 0, Convert.ToDateTime(item.DueDate));
    }

    //SORT RESULTS
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Sort and group the raw data
    var sorteditems = //sort and group the data table to show sum of qty per day per item
        (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
        orderby p.Field<string>("ItemID") , p.Field<DateTime>("DueDate")
        group p by new {ItemID = p.Field<string>("ItemID"), DueDate = p.Field<DateTime>("DueDate")}
        into g

        select new
                   {
                       g.Key.ItemID,
                       g.Key.DueDate,
                       QtyIn = g.Sum(p => p.Field<decimal>("QtyIn")),
                       QtyOut = g.Sum(p => p.Field<decimal>("QtyOut"))
                   }).ToList();

    //Create second DataTable to hold sorted and grouped report items
    //tried to use same datatable dt but it didn't work, no hardship to instantiate another
    var dt2 = new DataTable();

    dt2.Columns.Add("ItemID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt2.Columns.Add("QtyIn", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
    dt2.Columns.Add("QtyOut", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
    dt2.Columns.Add("DueDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));

    foreach (var item in sorteditems) //loop through the sorted results
    {
        //Move the sorted and grouped items into the datatable
        AddToItems(dt2, item.ItemID, Convert.ToDecimal(item.QtyIn), Convert.ToDecimal(item.QtyOut), Convert.ToDateTime(item.DueDate));
    }

    Session["MRPTable"] = dt2; //save datatable to session for recall later by repeater

    //Set repeater datasource to unique item list with details
    var itemslist = from si in sorteditems
                    group si by new { si.ItemID } into sig //equivilent to DISTINCT

                    join i in db.Items
                    on sig.Key.ItemID equals i.ItemID

                    select new
                    {
                        i.ItemID,
                        i.ItemName,
                        i.StocktakeCost,
                        i.ItemROP,
                        i.ItemROQ,
                        i.ItemUOM,
                        i.ItemStock
                    };

    Repeater1.DataSource = itemslist; //note repeater contains a GridView that contains the line items
    Repeater1.DataBind(); //Fire the repeater

    //time finished
    DateTime finishTime = DateTime.Now;

    //Set the start time label
    TimeStart.Text = startTime.TimeOfDay.ToString();

    //Set finish time
    TimeFinish.Text = finishTime.TimeOfDay.ToString();

    TimeTaken.Text = (finishTime - startTime).Minutes.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " Minute(s), " + (finishTime - startTime).Seconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " Seconds";

    //Add to activity log
    ActivityDAL.AddNewLog("MRP Report", "Generated", TimeTaken.Text, "N/A", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

}
```

Comment: Do you mean to group by the ComponentItemID or to add the ItemID into the select?

Comment: My bad, I have fixed it, try again. Wrote it with notepad, which doesn't have intellisense...

Comment: Code works perfectly! Thanks Ethan. Only problem is the time taken has now reduced to 78 seconds. Still, a marked improvement!

Comment: Do you have ANT profiler? Suggest you to download the trail version and profile your code. It will help

Comment: I cleaned the code a bit, should save few seconds. Also, I saw dt isn't need to be a DataTable, as it is not the result of the function. You should change it to a list of objects like OrderItem. Adding data into DataTable is slow as it will do some unneeded check.  and sort on DataTable are slow as well, given the underlying data structure is b-tree. Basically, if you can avoid using DataTable, do not use it, cause it is not light wight, and can be slow sometime

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this, fixed an errant join and reduced the report from 90 seconds to 5